# Looking for a STANDALONE SCRIPT for Custom Selectbox

Tags: drop-down-menu

I've been looking all day for a custom script that will stylize my select box with an image down arrow.  Nothing too fancy!  Everything out there has a combination of other features that messes up the rest of my existing form.

**Does anyone have a script that focuses only on custom Selectboxes at different widths on the same page/form?**  **JUST SELECTBOXES!**  No radio buttons, textareas, etc....  Just Select boxes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your other question on the select boxes for ryanfait.com script hopefully that does the trick but saw that you posted this as well.

**some options**

Seems like a simple jQuery plugin: http://www.brainfault.com/2007/07/23/select-box-replacement/

Complex css, but seems to work: http://gerrendesign.com/weblog/2009/06/how_to_make_custom_select_boxe.php

Good Article on how to build custom form elements from the ground up, tho I am guessing you just need a script this would be something to check out later: http://mondaybynoon.com/2009/02/23/creating-custom-form-elements-using-jquery-selects/

Hope your select boxes troubles are almost over.

Comment: awesome did the other answer work or what did you end up using?